# App crashes when click the facebook button

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

```
@IBAction func fbloginbtn(sender: AnyObject) {

            FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email","user_location","user_about_me", "user_photos", "user_website"],
                fromViewController:self,
                handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil){
                        let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                        if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                        {
                       //codess
                        }
                         )}
                        }
```

I used this code in an other app without a problem but this time it crashes the app. I don't know what the problem is.

[image]

I use xcode 7 and facebook SDK 4.6

any idea ?

Comment: The code you posted isn't calling `dispatch_once`. Where are you calling it?

Comment: i am calling it in a login view, login.swift

Comment: Update your question with the actual code causing the crash.

Comment: this is the only code that causes crash when fb button click